# How can I web scrape GitHub project contributor information in R?

Tags: r, api, github, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to write a function that extracts some contributor data from a GitHub project's contributor page. For example: https://github.com/easystats/report/graphs/contributors

How can I extract, using R, for example the username, number of commits, number of additions, and number of removals?

Here is my attempt at web scraping using `rvest` (https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest):

```r
library(rvest)

contribs <- read_html("https://github.com/easystats/report/graphs/contributors")

section <- contribs %>% html_elements("section")
section
#> {xml_nodeset (0)}

contribs$node
#> <pointer: 0x0000027d9b9e9f10>
contribs$doc
#> <pointer: 0x0000027d9e03d140>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

But I think I am not getting the expected result.

However, I would much prefer a solution where I could use an existing R package for this, or the GitHub API (https://github.com/r-lib/gh).
But is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found their API in the network section in the developer tools

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

"https://github.com/easystats/report/graphs/contributors-data" %>%
  request() %>%
  req_headers("x-requested-with" = "XMLHttpRequest",
              accept = "appliacation/json") %>%
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>%
  unnest(everything()) %>%
  group_by(username = str_remove(path, "/")) %>%
  summarise(across(a:c, sum)) 

# A tibble: 21 x 4
   username                a      d     c
   <chr>               <int>  <int> <int>
 1 DominiqueMakowski  203778 148154   325
 2 IndrajeetPatil      15082  10513   159
 3 LukasWallrich           1      1     1
 4 bwiernik             1371    156    11
 5 cgeger                  1      1     1
 6 drfeinberg            127     23     1
 7 dtoher                 26     26     1
 8 etiennebacher         127    162     7
 9 fkohrt                  1      1     1
10 grimmjulian             2      2     1
11 humanfactors           22     23     4
12 jdtrat                  1      1     1
13 m-macaskill            33     31     2
14 mattansb             1009    603    14
15 mutlusun              265      4     4
16 pkoaz                   3      2     1
17 rempsyc              3427   2938    14
18 strengejacke         5129  38164   223
19 vincentarelbundock      5      0     1
20 webbedfeet             85     85     2
21 wjschne                 2      2     1
```

Comment: That's incredible, thank you! Seems it was not straightforward to get the desired result, but it works very well. I tried to see if it would still work changing the link to other packages. Adding `check_type = FALSE` to the `httr2::resp_body_json` call makes it work for many packages, but sometimes I get the `Error in 'resp_body_raw()': ! Can not retrieve empty body` error. Still have to figure that one out.

Comment: I found the reason for that problem. The function cannot fetch the data if the data have not been updated. We need to manually visit the page and wait for the new data to process before we can call the function.